# Vba Macro para copiar y cambiar posición de las celdas en otra hoja

Tags: excel, vba, script

Antes de todo, agradeceros la ayuda por muy pequeña que sea.
Bien, pues me han mandado hacer una Macro en vba y soy bastante nuevo en esto y no sé cómo hacerlo exactamente(tengo ideas básicas de programación).
Me piden que copie los salarios de las personas que salen en el excel, que van desde la columna D hasta un número indefinido(Ya que puede ser que posteriormente se añadan más personas a la lista) a medida que en la columna B va encontrando números, cada vez que encuentre un número de la columna B tiene que copiar el salario, código de persona y nombre que sale en la columna correspondiente a las personas, así hasta el final.
[image: Así es como tengo el exel]

Así es cómo tiene que salir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Por favor, postea qué código has utilizado hasta ahora, y dónde estás teniendo problemas. SO es para resolver dudas específicas, no un servicio gratuito de escritura de código.

Answer (score 0):

la mejor forma para solucionar tu problema es utilizando bucles para recorrer las celdas y almacenarlas temporalmente en una variable String para escrbirlas nuevamente en formato tabla.

Podrías también trasponer los datos, pero no tendrás un control total como si lo manejaras de la forma anterior.

De igual forma lo normal para un manejo adecuado tendría que ser de la imagen b a la imagen a, ya que así tienes una matriz adecuada.

Cuéntame si pudiste resolver tu problema.

Saludos,
Nico